# How to include multiple message resources in Struts?

Tags: java, struts-1

I'm using (learning...) Struts 1.3 to build an MVC web application. For clarity, I'd like to include more than one `<message-resources>` element - separating the messages into files for specific modules of the application.

The official [Apache documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/userGuide/configuration.html) states:

> You can define one or more `<message-resources>` elements for your webapp; modules can define their own resource bundles. Different bundles can be used simultaneously in your application, the 'key' attribute is used to specify the desired bundle.

However, when I include more than one element, JSP's cause an exception stating that there is a missing message for key:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Missing message for key "label.username" in bundle "(default bundle)" for locale en_GB
at org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.MessageTag.doStartTag(MessageTag.java:233)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_bean_005fmessage_005f0(index_jsp.java:197)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:107) ~~~snip~~~
```

This is the XML:

```
<struts-config>
    ~~~snip~~~
    <message-resources parameter="resources.DefaultResource"/>
    <message-resources parameter="resources.Registration"/>    
</struts-config>
```

Without the second "Registration" resource, the exception isn't thrown. "label.username" exists in the "DefaultResource" only.

Many thanks.

Comment: @downvoter What do you feel is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With this struts-config, the second message resources element uses the same (default) key as the first one, and thus replaces the first one completely. You must assign a different key to each of the bundle, and use the bundle atttribute in the bean:message tag to indicate which bundle you want to use :

```
<struts-config>
    ~~~snip~~~
    <message-resources parameter="resources.DefaultResource"/>
    <message-resources parameter="resources.Registration" key="registrationBundle"/>    
</struts-config>
```

and in the JSPs :

```
Message from the default bundle : <bean:message key="my.first.key"/>
Message from the registration bundle : <bean:message key="my.second.key" bundle="registrationBundle"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to provide the key attribute. The key should be used in  tag in jsp to display particular message from the resource property file. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/11/multiple-message-resource-property-file-in-struts.html).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right there in the documentation snippet you included in your question.
if you have more than one bundle,

> Different bundles can be used simultaneously in your application, **the 'key' attribute is used to specify the desired bundle.**

http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/struts-core/dtddoc/struts-config_1_3.dtd.html#message-resources

Include a key attribute (with unique values) along with the parameter attribute in your struts-config. without a distinct key, resources.Registration is overwriting resources.DefaultResource 
(To test this assumption, switch the ordering of two message-resources in struts-config. Then, your label.username will work but messages from the other bundle won't)